# KeyboardOptions.Default.copy() vs KeyboardOptions(). When to use?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

This is from a TextField composable

When to use "Default Copy"? Does it matter?

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
    imeAction = ImeAction.Done, 
    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text
)
        
// vs //

keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
    imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to keep same instance and want to update one of the properties and preserve other ones you can use `.copy`().

Consider this example with a data class `Person`

```
data class Person(
    val name: String = "",
    val age: Int = 1
)
```

and some use-case like this

```
val johnPerson = Person("John", 21)
val unknownPerson = Person(age = 23)
```

I can simply copy unknownPerson and keep the age 23 and finally set the person's name like this

```
val knownPerson = unknownPerson.copy(name = "Mr. Kebab")
```

prints

```
Person(name=Mr. Kebab, age=23)
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter. They both end up doing the same thing. KeyboardOptions class is not a data class, and even if it were, the copy() method would still create a new instance.